# how to make secure requests that ipsec can't block

Tags: node.js, rest, server, restsharp, ipsec

so I'm trying to send requests from my mobile app to my node js server(that is running on windows) but the requests getting blocked by IPSEC because of a rule that I implemented which allows inbound connexions only if they are secure (authenticated and integrity protected). How can I make my requests secure ?
Im using restsharp to send the requests from my mobile app.

Comment: IPSec operates at the transport layer, which usually means the OS TCP/IP stack. REST frameworks work at the application layer, so it's unlikely that you can do what you want, the way you want to do it.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs I see what you are saying ! you are totally right !! Do you have any suggestions for how I can acheive that without modifying the rule ?